# Is Vishnu present in the current time?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, arjuna

I am very excited because yesterday I was viewing a Geeta shloka from a Mahabharata video present on YouTube. In the shloka, Krishna says to Arjuna:

> Partha, every time, you and me are present on the earth. It has never happened that you and me were not present.

So in this context, is Krishna present on the earth? If yes, where is he? Why he is not coming near people?

Comment: @KrishnShweta Thanks for your comment . You have seen   "Adbhut Avishwasniya " . How you forget about Vrindawan. Where after sunset nobody go there. All believe that krishna do Raas Lilla there everynight. But this is mythology there is no proof  of that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are referring to [verse 2.12](http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-2-12/).

> न त्वेवाहं जातु नासं न त्वं नेमे जनाधिपा | 
> न चैव न भविष्याम: सर्वे
>   वयमत: परम् || 12||
>
> na tvevāhaṁ jātu nāsaṁ na tvaṁ neme janādhipāḥ 
>  na chaiva na
>   bhaviṣhyāmaḥ sarve vayamataḥ param
>
> Never was there a time when I did not exist, nor you, nor all these
>   kings; nor in the future shall any of us cease to be.

This is how Adi Shankaracharya explains this verse. (Bhagavad Gita with commentary of Adishankaracharya translated by A Mahadeva Sastri).

> Never did I cease to exist ; on the other hand, I always did exist ;
>   that is, through the past bodily births and deaths, I always existed.
>   So also, never did you cease to exist ; on the other hand, you always
>   did exist. So, never did these rulers of men cease to exist ; on the
>   other hand, they always did exist. So, neither shall we ever cease to
>   exist ; on the other hand, we shall all certainly continue to exist
>   even after the death of these bodies. As the Self, the Atman, we are
>   eternal in all the three periods of time (past, present and future).
>
> The meaning is that even in all the three times (past, present and
>   future) we are eternal in our nature as the Self. The plural number
>   (in we) is used following the diversity of the bodies, but not in the
>   sense of the multiplicity of the Self.

According to Advaita, Nirguna Brahman alone exits and rest all dualities are just MAYA. Nirguna Brahman when seen through Maya appears as various dualities (good&bad, heat&cold, etc) and **in reality, Atman is Nirguna Brahman**. Lord Krishna/Brahman says that they both as self (Atman) exists eternally.

> If yes, where is He? Why he is not coming near people?

He is everywhere as He is the only eternal Truth. You must realize to know your true identity of Atman/Brahman. When required, He will indeed come to His true devotees in **Physical form**.

Comment: you just recited what's written in there. That's not a real answer.

Answer (score 7):

The Shloka that you are referring to is this one:

[image]

Word for word:

> na — never; tu — but; eva — certainly; aham — I; jātu — at any time;
>   na — did not; āsam — exist; na — not; tvam — you; na — not; ime — all
>   these; jana-adhipāḥ — kings; na — never; ca — also; eva — certainly;
>   na — not; bhaviṣyāmaḥ — shall exist; sarve vayam — all of us; ataḥ
>   param — hereafter.

Translation:

> Never was there a time when I did not exist, nor you, nor all these
>   kings; nor in the future shall any of us cease to be.

What one needs to be careful is about that Krishna is not talking about the physical body but about the Spirit. Hence, he is always there.

Regarding the second question, how do you know he is not coming near people? I know many who can vouch for that they have felt His presence.

Reference used: http://www.asitis.com/2/12.html

Comment: @Amit Saxena Thanks for your nice post. At you answer `how do you know he is not coming near people? I know many who can vouch for that they have felt His presence.` . Why vishnu saw and doing nothing like terrorist LIKE ISIS are killing people but he is doing nothing .

Comment: @A.Goutam This is Karma. When you are happy and enjoying life what did Vishnu do or what did you ask Him? Same now. If that Adharma reaches pinnacle, He will incarnate.

Comment: @TheDestroyer So you are thinking the Adharma is reaches pinnacle. How you can justify and what is apex of Adharma. How could you justify this

Comment: @A.Goutam That is a separate and a very deep question. Keep it with you. :)

Answer (score -1):

Again , best answer given by BrahmaKumaris ,
Yes , their souls were always present and are still  present now but not with the same bodies , after many births and rebirths they have become totally degraded now.
In the golden age they were the purest humans , worthy of worship deities , but presently in the iron age , they are as degraded and powerless as any one of us now.

Comment: You should cite sources.

Comment: I think there is no need to cite sources for this , it is simple logic. You agree there is a golden age when deities lived , where everything is pure and beautiful , you agree that the present is the iron age where everything is corrupt and ugly , you agree these souls were always present , how ? , there bodies are not present now , which means they must have taken rebirths.

Comment: and you as well agree to the concept of rebirth ,so logically these souls have also taken rebirth and if they are present in this age they should have the bodies and intellects of this age.