# Does following line states Brahma repeats same incidents everyday?

Tags: brahma

> BG 2.12 - But certainly never was a time, when I did not exist, nor you, nor these rulers of men. And surely it is not that we all shall cease to exist after this.

I read this line [on this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20415/when-brahmas-day-ends-and-a-new-day-starts-does-the-previous-day-repeat-itself) and it's stated that meaning of this line is that we all exist earlier also. This line is shown as proof that Cycle repeates same evens on each day of Brahma. Means I will be asking this same question on next day of Brahma also.

But there is some points which are contradicting with my information. For ex. It is said in same answer that "*whatever Shri Rama, Krishna, Shankara, Ganesha did during their live, exactly same things they will do in the next day of Brahma as well.*"

If the above mentioned statement about Rama/Krishna/Ganesha is true then this should also be true in case of Parvati... Isn't it? Because Parvati took birth as daughter of Haimalya. So that's mean She will take birth as daughter of Himalya on next day of Brahma also. BUT One day of Brahma is equal to 2 kalplas. So that's simply mean after 2 kampas Parvati will take birth as daghter of Himalya again. And She will continue to take birth as daughter of Himalya after every 2 kalpas(One brahma's day).

But there is one more fact that is conflictin with this. In post [What is the lifetime of parvati and present age of her?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21030/what-is-the-lifetime-of-parvati-and-present-age-of-her) the asnwer given that Parvati's lifetime is **6 months in the life of Brahma**. Now question here is that if Parvati will take birth as daughter of Himalya on every day of Brahma(after each 2 kalpa) then how her age can be six month of Brahma(aprox 360 kalpas)? Those two points/answers are contradicting with each other.

There are many more points can be found in which this theory(same events repeat on each day of Brahma) can leave so many questions and seems fake. Like Sati incident din't happened in this kalpa. I don't know in which Kalpa but no existance of Sati now and Parvati exist instead in this kalpa.

So by the above contradiction I conclude that meaning of above mentioned line is not what claimed in [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20415/when-brahmas-day-ends-and-a-new-day-starts-does-the-previous-day-repeat-itself). It must be some other meaning and need to find out. The correct meaning must not contradicting with any of other fact. Brahma's one day fact is also contradicting with other fact that Moksha is permanet state. So please give your views about it.

Comment: Related [Is Vishnu present in the current time?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14722/3500)

Comment: @thedestroyer I am interested to know whether this lines can be considered as proof that Every incident repeats on each day of Brahma? This was the main reason of asking this question as stated. I want to know about those contradiction which has mentioned in question.

Comment: Those lines say Atman is eternal. Krishna says every Jiva as Atma is eternal. Atma just changes body. This doesn't contradict if Devas leave bodies (as death is not proper term)

Comment: @Thedestroyer So that's mean fact "same incident repeats on each day of Brahma" is fake theory and moksha is also permanent state? If yes, then please post your views as answer. Because that theory only targets on bodies, not on aatma. Hence seems fake to me. That's why I asked so people don't get any misconception that moksha is not permanent.

Comment: There is a confusion. The line that - ***"The world comes again and again."***, does not mean that ***exactly same things happen.*** The thing is, that each time a **new creation happens again and again**, but the same thing will happen again and again is not mentioned.

Comment: @AnuragSingh That's exactly what I want to know. I wanted to check validity of [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20415/when-brahmas-day-ends-and-a-new-day-starts-does-the-previous-day-repeat-itself) Because by this answer it is being told in many posts that moksha is not permanent state, instead last only for 1 brahma day, which I thinks is not true. You can post answer to tell about this in brief.

Comment: Exactly same thing doesn't happen. However those events described by Vedas happen at all time. For eg. As Vedas say Vishwamitra heard Gayatri, in each creation there will be sage by name Vishwamitra (different Jeevas) and all will hear Gayatri and so on  for other events too which are described in Vedas.

Comment: YES, @Rishabh your comment on that answer was correct. Vishnu says- "Everything happens again and again" means that the process of creation, preservation, and dissolution happens again and again, but it is not at all stated that each time the things will be same. In fact, after 100 years of Brahma, a new Brahma will be appointed(probably Hanumaan, correct me if wrong?). So there is no question of similarity, because Brahma himself is changing.

Comment: @tezz So if I got moksha that will be permanent I guess. I am getting so much relief now because I was being told that moksha is not permanent on behalf of this theory. I had discussion in chat room with user who post the answer and he claimed moksha is not permanent.

Comment: Yes, Upanishads say Moksha is permanent state ... (however there can be various philosophical arguments for eg. People of Arya Samaj claim that Moksha isn't permanent).. however it's possible that when you get moksha in another creation another user by name Rishabh exactly asks this question (but this isn't you)... 

Answer (score 1):

<sub>I would have refrained to answer as it contradicts so many other people's views. Since you had asked me [in this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66749/discussion-between-iammilind-and-rishabh) to respond to this post, I am writing this answer. :-)</sub>

---

> > *"Parvati will take birth as daghter of Himalya again. And She will continue to take birth as daughter of Himalya after every 2 kalpas(One brahma's day)."*

Yes. Exactly same as: *""whatever Shri Rama, Krishna, Shankara, Ganesha did during their live, exactly same things they will do in the next day of Brahma as well."*

BTW, the Parvati post is from the mythology perspective. I can't relate to this post.

> > *"Brahma(after each 2 kalpa) then how her age can be six month of Brahma(aprox 360 kalpas)?"*

If you are referring mythological 4 headed Brahma-deva, then we are on different lines. Regarding philosophical interpretation of *Brahma*, I have described in following answer, that how **Brahma's cycle is only of 1 day** (or 1 day & 1 night):
[How do Brahma and Saraswati die?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21443/1049)

> > *"Does following line states Brahma repeats same incidents everyday?"*

**Yes**, this is already answered here:
[When Brahma's day ends and a new day starts does the previous day repeat itself?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20415/1049)

> > *"There are many more points can be found in which this theory(same events repeat on each day of Brahma) can leave so many questions and seems fake."*

In general following philosophical concepts are well founded and existent even before Mahabharata times:

- [Wheel of Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_of_time) (*KaalaChakra*, Hinduism, Buddhism, Sikkhism)
- [Eternal Return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_return) (multiple cultures)
- [Oscillating Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_model) (by Albert Einstein)

They all collectively say that, all the event recur without any change. That is the only way the current existence can be possible. Hence, kindly think of this as a general theory and not my own byproduct. :-)
Either one "knows" this theory or one "believes" otherwise.

---

Your main concern seems, if the Moksha is permanent state of not. That's answered here:
[What will happen when all atmans get moksha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10008/1049)

**For all practical purposes the Moksha is permanent state. The definition itself is "no rebirth".**
Now if you consider, multiple cycles then Moksha will not look like permanent state.

**Analogy**: If we watch a cricket match in a TV, then certain events would be happening in that match. 1 team may win. Now how many times, we watch the repeat telecast, the same events will happen and the same team will win.

While watching the cricket match for the very first time, a viewer has certain excitement & uncertainty. In repeat telecast, it diminishes. But in the *mAyA* of *Brahma* cycles, this doesn't happen. Because the memory is not carry forwarded to the next cycle.
In other words, the viewer of *mAyA* watches the match with same excitement & uncertainty. Every time is the first time, though repeating infinitely.
Hope this clears some of the doubts.

---

**Meta**

> > <sub>*"So by the above contradiction **I conclude** that meaning of above mentioned line is not what claimed in this post."*</sub>

<sub>IMO, this is not the right way to ask a Qn. Had you asked this in main SO, then it would have closed quickly, as you are actually not asking a real Qn. But verifying the already made opinion.</sub>

Comment: Still doubt remains. On behalf of which scriptures reference you are saying everything will repeat? Mentioned verse's meaning can be considered in many ways. Many users in comment has explained diff meaning of verse than your. So the verse you showed as proof, that verse is not saying exact same even will repeat with same aatma. Body and name may be same but aatma will also same?, it's not possible since your given verse is not saying that.

Comment: Grab meaning of every single word in your given verse and tell me where your verse is saying aatma will also same in next day of Brahma?

Comment: @Rishabh, you asked me to answer, so I have put forward my opinion. Others users may put theirs. It's up to you, what you want to accept. Regarding "Atma" being different or not, is irrelevant, because *Atma* is referred as "nothingness" (*neti neti*). So if you say, *"body will be same, aatma will be different"* is equivalent to say *"body will be same, 'nothing' will be different"*! I agree, 'nothing' will be different. :-) -- Now if you are wondering why *Atma* is referred as "nothingness", then either you may refer numerous of my previous answers or ask a new Qn to know different opinions.

Comment: _"so I have put forward my opinion. Others users may put theirs"_ How can you write answer on great divine state moksha on just behalf of your opinion. You think moksha is only for one cycle, then it is just your opinion as you said. Since you have alrady answered then why you didn't add this line in you answer that _"It is just my personal opinion"_? You should have add this line(my personal opinion) in those post also where you claim that everything repeats... Isn't it?

Answer (score -1):

If at all everything is repeated periodically, we have no control over the event horizon at all. This simply means, the karma we are doing (like, I am typing presently) was done earlier by me plenty of times. Thus, the typing is independent of my will and wish. In the same way, killing of people by someone is predetermined and has occurred plenty of times. Not only that, (s)he will do it again plenty of times.

If that is the case, why one the earth did Lord Krishna showed us the Karma Yog? Nothing is in our hand, not even karma. If you sneeze now then rest assured you have done it periodically in every day of Brahma.

Then there is no Dharma, no Karma, no Jnana nothing is needed. Thus, it sounds ridiculous to even think the periodic events.

Of course, the universe is expanding and blackholes have been collecting the matter. Again, the universe will collapse and the big bang will take place. Again on some planet, the life will take place. But there is nothing like the earth will be filled with the same people bearing the same names, living in the same places as in the earlier cycle.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).