# Was there ever a time when I was not there?

Tags: atma

My questions are simple(both from advaita and dvaita point of views):

Was there ever a time when I was not there?

If yes then how did I come into being and from what ?

If no then have I lived infinite number of ignorant lives ?

Comment: "Never was there a time when I did not exist, nor you, nor all these kings; nor in the future shall any of us cease to be." BG 2.12 Don't you know this one?

Comment: Ya.. never was Ther a tym wen u dint exist. You never came into being.yes we have lived for infinite years of ignorance. Read chpt 2 of gita.

Comment: Oh my God. I have been living for infinite number of years. But that is not true. We have been living for infinite number of years.

Comment: *But that is not true.* What is not true?

Comment: It is not true that I have been alone living for infinite number of years. We ,including you and me, have been living for infinite number of years. There never was a time when WE did not exist. People fail to appreciate this fact. If I take rebirth , my Universe will still consist of you , my parents, my helpers, my friends, my relatives probably in a different relational arrangement.

Comment: Yes, you have been living for infinite number of years and other people also have been living for infinite number of years. That's true. -- *have I lived infinite number of ignorant lives?* Gaudiya Vaishnavas (I subscribe to their system of Vedanta) believe that we have not been born for infinite number of lives so far. Gaudiyas believe that we had the 1st birth in samsara (repeated births and deaths) and thus the number of our lives in samsara is finite. It is not infinite!

Comment: @brahmajijnasa Which lessons I failed to learn in all these infinite years that I have still not got Moksha?:-) (Gaudiya Vaishnavas need not answer that) If Moksha is a possibility inherent in the nature then I should have got Moksha by now. But since that has not happened, it means that I have suffered infinite number of times. Krishna has already failed... If I pray to Krishna "Lord , I have suffered infinite number of times, give me Moksha" Will he give me Moksha ? No He will not. "I had infinite births" theory is wrong.

Comment: Then it seems you are feeling as if you are hopeless :) Cheer up, be bold and take the path towards moksha as Lord Krishna has explained in the Bhagavad gita. Yeah, infinite births theory is wrong.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa I am not hopeless. Without hurting the sentiments I would like to ask if I had not had infinite births then where did I came from ? (Pls put that as an answer.)

Comment: See the question and read all the comments here: *Is there the first birth of a jiva soul in the material world or not?* https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16683/2790

Answer (score 2):

I am putting some of the [Nog Shine's](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/5212/nog-shine) comments in my answer.

Gita 2.12

> Never was there a time when I did not exist, nor you, nor all these kings; nor in the future shall any of us cease to be.

That means, everyone of us as this body always existed in certain period of time. However, we as this same body, did not exist before our birth and after our death.

Gita 2.27, 2.28

> One who has taken his birth is sure to die, and after death one is sure to take birth again. Therefore, in the unavoidable discharge of your duty, you should not lament. All created beings are unmanifest in their beginning, manifest in their interim state, and unmanifest again when annihilated. So what need is there for lamentation?

From Rigveda:

> सूरय्याचन्द्रमसौ धाता यथा पूर्वमकल्पयत् I दिवं च पृथ्वीं च अंतरिक्षमथो स्वः
>   The Ordainer created the sun and moon like those of previous cycles. He formed in order Heaven and Earth, the regions of the air, and light.

If the Ordainer keeps creating sun, moon etc. in same way then humans like us also should be created in same way.

Don't know how are you/me born though. :-)

Comment: **सूरय्याचन्द्रमसौ धाता यथा पूर्वमकल्पयत् I दिवं च पृथ्वीं च अंतरिक्षमथो स्वः** Does this verse apply on everything? If yes, then Where is Sati in this kalpa who was present in previous kalpa. And also why Pravati exist since she wasn't present in previous kalpa?

Comment: "If the Ordainer keeps creating sun, moon etc. in same way then humans like us also should be created in same way." Only characters mentioned in Vedas are created in same way as mentioned by Vedas. For eg in each creation there is Vishwamitra, there is Dadhichi, there is Vasistha etc. .. and they do activities described in Vedas... but this doesn't mean that every character of present also shall exactly repeat in the same way...

Answer (score 0):

Your body sure never exist before but your soul was/is/will exist. Because soul is free from Kal chakra. Soul can't be effect by time, only our body take effects of time in which he/she grow old and die.

**Note**:
 Some people think everything repeats in every kalpa. For exampla: I will be giving same answer in next kalpa also. They also claim that all incarnations also repeat. For ex: Rama/Krishna/Ganesha etc will take birth in next kalpa also. But this theory is fake. Here is how...

If everything reapeats means everything(whole creation) inluding vedas, puranas, Incarnations ect. But if we will see information about previous kalpas (previous days of Brahma) then we will come to know that everything is not repeating. Just have a look on following incidents which hasn't repeat...
I am goint to show you some examples which are not repeating

**Note**: I said some examples that doesn't mean there is not more examples which are not repeating. It's Just 2 or 3 exampels is enough to prove this theory is fake.

> **Puranas are not repeating**

As par Matasya Purana explains that each Purana is being created in which Kalpa. Here is the list..

> - Padma Purana                        - Padma Kalpa (hence the name)
> - Vishnu Purana                       - Varaha Kalpa (current Kalpa)
> - Vayu Purana (includes Shiva Purana) - Sveta Kalpa
> - Bhagavata Purana                    - Sarsvata Kalpa
> - Naradiya Purana                     - Brhat Kalpa
> - Agni Purana                         - Isana Kalpa
> - Bhavishya Purana                    - Aghora Kalpa
> - Brahma Vaivarata Purana             - Rathantara Kalpa
> - Linga Purana                        - Agneya Kalpa
> - Varaha Purana                       - Manava Kalpa
> - Skanda Purana                       - Satpurusha Kalpa
> - Vamana Purana                       - Kurma Kalpa
> - Kurma Purana                        - Lakshmi Kalpa
> - Matsya Purana                       - Vaivastara Manvantara of Varaha Kalpa
> - Brahmanda Purana                    - Future Kalpas (No specific name mentioned)

Brhama day and night is equal to 2 kalpas. So those Puranas are not being made in one or two kalpas. So this theory completely falls down in case of Puranas.
**Reference For above statements**:
[Is each of the 18 Mahapurans related to a different Kalpa?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21446/is-each-of-the-18-mahapurans-related-to-a-different-kalpa)

> **Incarnations also not repeating**

Let's see example of Sati(incarnation of Aadi Shakti)who was incarnated in **Pitri Kalpa**. After her death she didn't take incarnation for whole one day of brahma.
And after one day of Brahma Aadi Shakti took incarnation as Parvati. These information are being told by Shiva himself to Parvati..

> O beautiful lady, due to the anger of Daksha you had to be separated from me for the duration Of a day Of Brahma. Your span of life is the period of his six months.

Long story short, Sati was exist in previous kalpa, not in this one. If everything repeats then there should be a Sati in this Kalpa also But we don't have. Instead we have Mata Parvati.

So according to above statement of Shiva (mentioned in Chapter 19, Prabhasa Khanda of Skanda Purana) Shiva told to Parvati that I was sapareted to you(from Sati's death to Parvati's birth) for whole one day of Brahma.
Shiva also told that you age as Parvati will be 6 months of Brahma. Here are following points to notice...

Sati was born aprox. past day of Brahma, so where is Sati now in current day of Brahma Same goes to Parvati. Why we have Parvati now instead of Sati?
Parvati's (daughter of Himalya) age is being told 6 months of Brhama(approx 360 kalpas). If everything repeats in every kalpa then how parvati's age can be 360 kalpas?

So this is how this theory again falls down badly and breaks it's teeth by saying everything will repeat.

**Reference For above statements**
[What is the lifetime of parvati and present age of her?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21030/what-is-the-lifetime-of-parvati-and-present-age-of-her/#answer-21039)
[How many kalpas ago was Sati born?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21463/how-many-kalpas-ago-was-sati-born)

> **Everything is not repeating is clear now. But from where this myth originated that everything will repeat?**

This myth is originated from confusion of one verse of Geeta. Here is that verse...

> न त्वेवाहं जातु नासं न त्वं नेमे जनाधिपा |
>   न चैव न भविष्याम: सर्वे वयमत: परम् || 12||
>
> na tvevāhaṁ jātu nāsaṁ na tvaṁ neme janādhipāḥ
>   na chaiva na bhaviṣhyāmaḥ sarve vayamataḥ param
>
> Never was there a time when I did not exist, nor you, nor all these kings; nor in the future shall any of us cease to be.

Some people pointed out wrong meaning from this verse. See this whole verse word to word. And check every single word in this verse, and think where it is being said everything will repeat.

Actually this verse is targeting on soul(aatma), not on body. Means Krishna said we are were present earlier as aatm because aatma never born not dies. So aatma was/will always present.

Correct meaning of verse is being explained [HERE](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14722/is-vishnu-present-in-the-current-time/#answer-14724) and [HERE](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14722/is-vishnu-present-in-the-current-time/#answer-14723) which says we all were exist earlier and will exist after as aatma. Body dies but aatma never dies.

> **Reference for above statement**:
>   [Is Vishnu present in the current time?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14722/is-vishnu-present-in-the-current-time/#answer-14724)

Comment: They repeat. Creation, sun, moon etc., repeat. This from Rig Veda. सूरय्याचन्द्रमसौ धाता **यथा पूर्वमकल्पयत् I** दिवं च पृथ्वीं  च अंतरिक्षमथो स्वः   II"The Ordainer created the sun and moon **like those of previous cycles**. He formed in order Heaven and Earth, the regions of the air, and light." 10.190.3. There can't be great reference than Veda.  From Padma Purana, Kriya Yogasara Kanda. Vishnu says Brahma to create everything just how he did in the previous Kalpa.  So, the answer is they repeat. But why did you write all this stuff? That is not related to the question.

Comment: @nogshine Sun, moon are need that's why they need to be create again. What I am saying is different. What ever point I said in my answer, you have any point to make them false? Planets and lokas also will b create again, else where were human live. It's obvious.

Comment: @nogshine Answer me.. Can you prove my raised points(in given answer about puranas, incarnation) wrong? Can you prove Sati's existence in current kalpa since she was present in prev. kalpa? And other points of mine also.

Comment: Why are you in a hurry? O-o.  Use chat for discussion.

Comment: @NogSHine I don't know how to create chat. Just tell me here, if everthing repeats then Where is Sati in this kalpa who was present in previous kalpa. And also why Pravati exist since she wasn't present in previous kalpa? And yes, take your time.

Comment: May I know the reasons of down votes since I have given all valid references in support of my answer... I am surprised a question with references is getting down votes!!